# URL rewriting: Change mydomain.com/index.php to mydomain.com/home

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am working with `PHP` and I want to change this url `mydomain.com/index.php` to this `mydomain.com/home` so wrote the following code:

```html
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule home index.php
```

When I go to `mydomain.com/home` it works but when I go to `mydomain.com/index.php` the url does not change to `mydomain.com/home`

How can I solve this problem, please ?

Comment: Are you using codeigniter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try :

```
RewriteEngine on
#externally redirect "/index.php" to "/home"
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/index\.php
RewriteRule ^ /home [L,R]
#internally map "/home" back to "/index.php"
RewriteRule home index.php
```

Comment: Oops, I am facing a problem: even if i try to access a link looking like this `mydomain/folder/index.php`, I am redirected to `mydomain/index.php`

Comment: @prince I have fixed the RewriteCond ,now it wont match your subfolders but root.

Comment: Working perfectly. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Example**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule index.php http://example.com/home [L,R=301]
```

Comment: What is the **&** for?

Comment: This line was from my .htaccess code. I removed the line now because it was optional. It was to set de default path to http://example.com/home